# Terraform : How to hookup azurerm_api_management_authorization_server to azurerm_api_management_api

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-api-management

Hi and thanks for taking the time to look at my question.

I'm using terraform to create an api_management object in Azure.  I've mastered the setup of API's, Products, Policies, Subscriptions and Users.

My devs setup an authorisation server on the API Management object in Azure, which I automated using azurerm_api_management_authorization_server which works fine.

However, I can't see how in terraform I can configure the API settings to use that authorisation server.
[API User Authorisation Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weBGO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks as if this capability is currently not available via Terraform, which can be found by the open issue against the `azurerm` provider:
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3341

What I would recommend doing to let you continue building out your infrastructure within Terraform, would be to utilise the [azurerm_template_deployment](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/template_deployment.html) resource.

This would let you utilise the available ARM API's from an ARM deployment:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/2019-01-01/service/apis

Sadly, until that issue is closed that capability won't be in the `azurerm` provider.

Comment: Thx Lachie, also a viable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note to the Answer provided by Lachie White

As I'm running this from a yaml pipeline in azure devops, I got around this limitation by using an azure powershell task

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'Subscription (111111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111)'
          ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
          Inline: |
            $ApiMgmtContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "api-mgmt-rg" -ServiceName "api-mgmt"
            $ApiAuthorizationServer = Get-AzApiManagementAuthorizationServer -Context $ApiMgmtContext
            $ApiAuthorizationServerName = $ApiAuthorizationServer.Name
            Set-AzApiManagementApi -Context $ApiMgmtContext -ApiId "api-name" -AuthorizationServerId "$ApiAuthorizationServerName"
         azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```